# Edit the display of an element during a jquery change event in Chrome and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm having issues getting form elements to style correctly during a change event. The event does a lot of processing and takes a couple of seconds to process so I want to disable the inputs while the event is loading.

At the moment I'm doing:

```
$( '#checkbox' ).on('change', function() {
    $('#textField').prop('disabled', true);
    //process some stuff
    $('#textField').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

This works fine in firefox but does not seem to work in Chrome or IE. In chrome and ie the actual disabled attribute is updated correctly but the display of the textfield doesnt update until the entire change function has finished.

Is there a way to force chrome and ie to update the styling of the disabled input in the middle of the change function?

Comment: You could push your process to a webworker, then it'll be handled in a non-blocking way. But it seems strange. Modifying a DOM property is a synchronous action. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this actually demonstrates that what you are trying to do works on IE, but this works for me on IE.

Could you possibly call your long-running function in a setTimeout with a callback to a function that re-enables your textbox?

```js
$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $('#textField').prop('disabled', true);
  setTimeout(function() {
    // long processing here.

    // re-enable textbox here.
    $('#textField').prop('disabled', false);
     // probably use something like 50ms so your function has a slight
     // delay for Chrome to be able to update the UI, but not too long
     // to stall your function.
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Check me.
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="textField" value="text here" />
</div>
```

I also found this post about how to avoid blocking the UI thread when running CPU intensive javascript.
https://benjaminhorn.io/code/cpu-intensive-javascript-computations-without-blocking-the-single-thread/

Comment: Thanks, the timeout idea worked. Even setting it to 1ms was enough to get the UI to update straight away.